# Question "Scope Creep"

Tags: discussion, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Exit strategies for “chameleon questions”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43478/exit-strategies-for-chameleon-questions)

The only way I know how to describe this is as *scope creep* so I apologize if I've overlooked a duplicate question.

This afternoon I provided an answer to [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9114078/tell-if-a-drive-is-a-partition-or-a-seperate-hdd/9114165) which was left fairly open. My answer provided the result from another question which satisfied the general question asked. My answer was upvoted and maked as the answer to their question. All is good and fine in the world of SO.

Tonight I checked in just in time to find out that my answer has been unmarked as the answer (hence removing 15 rep) and a comment left in its place asking for further implementation details which are beyond the scope of the original question.

Is it just me or should this be a separate question? Put more generally: how should this be handled?

Comment: @random - I generally agree that the question you specified as a dupe is the same question though it doesn't reference the case where the original asker *actually* marked an answer as the answer. I know this seems like a small detail, however to close a question as answered and open it up again because the OP couldn't figure it out (even given proper documentation)... just seems ridiculous. It almost seems necessary that SO require a waiver to be signed by the asked upon selection of an answer that states that the question as asked ha been answered.

Comment: This is one of the potential problems with spending effort on such questions in the first place.